# Test ended error is encountered for route.fetch

Tags: typescript, playwright

I am automating reactjs page, while running the test with route.fetch() function, I am getting the error below.

> Error: route.fetch: Test ended.
> Call log:
>
> - → GET /analytics?startDate=2024-02-11T13:00:00.000Z&endDate=2024-03-13T12:59:59.999Z
> - user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.6167.57 Safari/537.36

Here's my code

```
await page.route("**/analytics?startDate=**", async (route) => {
    const response = await route.fetch();
    const result = await response.json();
    const respBody = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
    expect(response.status()).toBe(200);
    expect(respBody["own"]).not.toBeNull;
    expect(respBody).toHaveProperty(child1);

    return route.continue();
});

await PW.visit(route_dashboard_page, page);
await dashboard.awaitDashboardLoaded();
```

It was working fine previously in non-react page. May I know the possible reason why is this happening?